# EF Linq query to get count of categories

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

in an asp.net MVC application with EF I return a list of categories to a multi-select box.

For each category I would like to count the number of occurrences in the DB and display it in the same select box like **"Category A (Count: 77)"**

Here's the code I have to return all my distinct categories:

```
private List<Categories> GetCategories()
{
    using (myEntities dc = new myEntities())
    {
        List<Categories> categoryList = dc.View.Select(
            t => new Categories
            {
                category = t.category,
                categoryOutput = t.category + "Count: "
            })
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(t => t.category)
            .ToList();

    return categoryList;
    }
}

public class Categories
{
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string categoryOutput { get; set; }
}
```

Can you show me what needs to be added in order to calculate the count for each category?

**UPDATE:**

thanks for the explanation with GroupBy!
How does it work with multiple properties, for example an additional "**categoryCode**":

```
public class Categories { 
public string category { get; set; } 
public string categoryCode { get; set; } 
public string categoryOutput { get; set; } }
```

Thank you

Comment: Try `categoryOutput = t.category.Distinct().Count()`

Comment: @ShawnYan That will just give you the number of categories, not the count of items in each category

Comment: @Rhumborl I see , so you need GroupBy to seperate each category and count from there. My mistake :-)

Comment: @ShawnYan Exactly :) Glad to help you understand better

Answer (score 3):

You need [`GroupBy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
List<Categories> categoryList = dc.View
        .GroupBy(t => t.category)
        .Select(t => new Categories
        {
            // t is now essentially an enumerable with a Key property
            category = t.Key, // Key is what we grouped by (category)
            categoryOutput = t.Key + "Count: " + t.Count().ToString()
        })
        //.Distinct() // no need for this now
        .OrderBy(t => t.category)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. What if I needed to include more class properties?
Like:  
`public class Categories
{
    public string category { get; set; }
public string categoryCode { get; set; }
    public string categoryOutput { get; set; }
}
`